# Simplifying PHP if's and arrays

Tags: php

I have a piece of code I just wrote that detects if there is a user logged in and if [1] and [2] have any specific text in the string and then will relocate that person to another page if the values are met.

But I think my code is a little long winded. Is there a way to simplify what I have or is this the best I'll get?

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){  
    $dir =  dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $dirs = explode('/', $dir);
    if(isset($dirs[1])){
        if (($dirs[1] == "account") || ($dirs[1] == "admin")){
            header('Location: /');
        }
    }
    if(isset($dirs[2])){
        if(($dirs[2] == "account")){
            header('Location: /');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you can use mod_rewrite and specify rewrite rules for those paths?

Comment: Have amended code, the piece is inside an if statement to check whetehr user is logged in or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way is to use a closure

```
$dir =  explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

$is = function($pos, $check) use($dir) {
    return array_key_exists($pos, $dir) && $dir[$pos] == $check;
};

if($is->__invoke(1, 'account')
    || $is->__invoke(1, 'admin')
    || $is->__invoke(2, 'account')) {
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do that for instance:

```
$dir =  dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$dirs = explode('/', $dir);

if(in_array('account',$dirs) || in_array('admin', $dirs)){
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Comment: and now a combination of Bgi & James: `if (in_array(array('account', 'admin'), $dirs)) header('Location: /');`

Comment: I replaced header with an echo to test the page response. It returns nothing.

Comment: Have a var_dump($dirs) before the if to check that the $dirs is correctly created

Comment: Dump returns array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(7) "account" }

Answer (score 0):

One of a few simpler solutions could be to use PHP's `array_intersect($array1, $array2)` function. This is well documented on the [php.net website](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php), but here's a little example:

```
// Define all the 'search' needles
$needles = array('account', 'admin');

// Get all the dirs
$dirs = explode('/', dirname( $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ));

// Check for needles in the hay
if( array_intersect($needles, $dirs) )
{    
    // Redirect
    header('Location: /');    
}
```

**ADDED:** You could of course make the above very simple by combining multiple lines into one, this would leave you with:

```
if( array_intersect(array('account', 'admin'), explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) )
{
    header('Location: /');
}
```

Comment: I replaced header with an echo to test the page response. It returns nothing.

Comment: What is your URL for the site? It would return only one array item: '/' if your URL was something like: site.com/index.php, however if the URL was site.com/admin/index.php, you'd get two: '/' & 'admin'

Comment: OK, I've done some further research, and found another PHP function which is more reliable with comparing two arrays - array_intersect(). I'll update my post to use this instead.

Comment: A dump returns Dump returns array(2) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(7) "account" }

Comment: The above edited post will now work with the data you've got. It might also be a good idea to ensure the $dir variable is forced to lower-case using PHP's strtolower($str) function, in case you have account & Account for what ever reasons.